# How Can I make a very simple vbs code run on startup

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

This is the code

```
Dim voice 
Set voice = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") 
voice.speak "The FBI is watching you!" 
Wscript.Quit
```

It is for a prank on my cousin.

Comment: put the .vbs file inside the startup folder, go to run type ***shell:startup*** later press enter, it will show your startup folder.

Comment: Where Is the startup folder ??

Answer (score 3):

In Windows:

go to run command, there you type the command ***`shell:startup`***, press enter it will show you your startup folder and for me my startup folder is:

> ***C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup***

Comment: Putting any application or shortcut inside this `Startup` folder, would run this application on desktop load.